# How can I activate the pg_cron scheduler session?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13, pg-cron

I am using the pg_cron extension for scheduled tasks in PostgreSQL. While monitoring active sessions due to intermittent interruptions in my database, I noticed that the 'postgres' user was running a long-lasting session. This session had an Application Name of 'pg_cron scheduler' and a command of;

```
update cron.job_run_details set status = $1, return_message = $2, end_time = $3 where runid = $4.
```

Since the session duration was excessively long, I terminated this session, and afterward, my jobs stopped running. How can I re-enable the session?

Comment: Restart the server?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. The database needs to be actively running without interruption.

Comment: If I understand this issue [pg_cron restart](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron/pull/286) you need to restart the server for pg_cron 1.5-.

Comment: Lesson to be learned: *Never, ever for terminate a session until you **know** what process it contains and the repercussions of aborting that process.*  So what if it is a long running session, it just might be designed that way. Apparently, pg_cron starts when the server starts and and ends when the server shuts down (or its session is terminated.

Comment: Yes I learned my lesson. From now on, I will not make the mistake of terminating this process. I can't restart the server, but I did restart the cluster. A new session has been opened, but unfortunately my cron jobs are still not working.
New session;
`update cron.job_run_details set status = 'failed', return_message = 'server restarted' where status in ('starting','running')`

I think it will stay like this until I restart the server